# Existence of solution to Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

Given condition: Let $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Suppose there exist $w(>0)\in H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ satisfying the inequality $-\Delta w\leq C e^w$ in $\Omega$ for some positive constant $C$.
Can you please help me with the following question.

Does there exist some function $v\in H_{0}^1(\Omega)\cap C^1(\Omega)$ such that $w\leq v$ and satisfying $-\Delta v=Ce^{v}$ in $\Omega$.